# How to create a Event Emitter and Handler in rust with the help of Enums

Tags: multithreading, networking, rust, event-handling, rust-tokio

I am looking for a way to emit events and handle the events in rust like

```rust
enum Events {
    Message(String),
    Channel(i64),
    Disconnect(i16),
    Connect(JSON),
    HeartBeat
}
```

I want to listen for these events and create a handler for it. Similar to the one implemented in https://github.com/twilight-rs/twilight code example below.

Here is a short snippet for the above repo

```rust
loop {
        let event = match shard.next_event().await {
            Ok(event) => event,
            Err(source) => {
                tracing::warn!(?source, "error receiving event");

                if source.is_fatal() {
                    break;
                }

                continue;
            }
        };

        // Update the cache with the event.
        cache.update(&event);

        tokio::spawn(handle_event(event, Arc::clone(&http)));
    }

async fn handle_event(
    event: Event,
    http: Arc<HttpClient>,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
    match event {
        Event::MessageCreate(msg) if msg.content == "!ping" => {
            http.create_message(msg.channel_id)
                .content("Pong!")?
                .await?;
        }
        // Other events here...
        _ => {}
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

I am Expecting it to get the event through axum post request and handle the event using enum (fire the function) also is it possible to multi thread this? using tokio

Comment: So implement that, what's stopping you? As posted this question is way too broad, you can read [ask] to see what's expected, a specific problem which has a clear answer, not a general problem statement which can be implemented in countless different ways.

Comment: I am fairly new to rust but i want to know how the event is emited. I didn't really understand much from this https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-create-and-fire-event-listener/32617